# Convert in memory POCO objects to c# code to initialize

Tags: c#, serialization, automated-tests, poco

Is there a library or code sample for converting an in memory POCO c# object to a .cs code file that creates that object. An example:
object of type car in memory becomes:

```
Car c = new Car 
{ 
     Name = "mazda", 
     Id = 5,
     Passengers = new List<string> { "Bob", "Sally" }
     // etc... recursing to the bottom
};
```

I could assume it could only set public properties.

Comment: Have you tried combining Reflection with the codedom classes?  You should be able to generate classes with nothing but properties pretty easily.

Comment: I have played around with using reflection, but it gets a little hairy around generics and indexed objects.  I'm wondering if there anyone has already looked at this.  I've never looked at codedom, I'll take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a Visual Studio Extension (OmarElabd/ObjectExporter) which generates C# initializer code at debug-time. I personally needed to generate C# code from in-memory objects at runtime. This is what evolved from the original problem: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectDumper.NET/

ObjectDumper.Dump(obj, DumpStyle.CSharp); returns C# initializer code from a variable. The output string you may simply want to write to a file using File.WriteAllText method.

Answer (score 0):

We've used [binary serialization to serialize objects to file](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file), but nothing to readable .CS files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Visual Studio T4 code templates to gen your .cs files. You can check out the info on the code generation tools in [this article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2009/05/01/Visual-Studios-T4-Code-Generation.aspx) and see if its what your looking for.

You would need to setup a partial code template and have your library function write out the rest of the code template, then run the templates to generate your .cs class that creates your POCO objects. Not sure if this is the only way to do it but I could see it working.